# How to send serialized object to a servlet using Apache HttpClient

Tags: servlets, serialization, http-post, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I have a `Main()` class where I serialize an object of a class called `Names`. I am using `Apache HttpClient`'s `HttpPost()` to call a `servlet`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Names names = new Names();
    names.setName("ABC");
    names.setPlace("Bangalore");
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Name.txt"));
    out.writeObject(names);
    out.close();

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:6080/HttpClientGson/FirstHttpPostServlet");
```

Now, how do I send the `ObjectOutputStream` object? I wrote the following line
`httppost.setEntity(out)`

But `setEntity()` can only take objects of `HttpEntity` type. Is there any other method of `HttpClient` that I can use to send serialized object?

Comment: You need to send a `multipart/form-data` request. However, you're going totally the wrong direction in using Java serialization instead of more reuseable/exchangeable data transfer formats such as JSON/XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `SerializableEntity` class shipped with HttpClient

```
httpost.setEntity(new SerializableEntity(mySerializableObj, false));
```

Please note, though, that binary object serialization should be used only when absolutely required. Other serialization formats such as XML or JSON should generally be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XStream to serialize an object to XML/JSON.
http://x-stream.github.io/
and then to pass it.