# Deserialization of the Java object in using Apache HttpClient Api is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am new to the Spring MVC. I am using the Spring release 4.1.6 and deployed my two web applications A and B on tomcat 7 for the development environment. But in the actual production environment the application A will be deployed on weblogic and application B will be deployed on websphere. Below is the scenario occuring on the development environment.

From the Application A , I am submitting the jsp page and invoked the below method of the controller. From this method I am creating the HttpPost request and sending the RequestDetails domain object to the another controller's method using ApacheHttpClient api.This is the code from the sender's side or from Application A's controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/httprequestJinesh.cvr",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String createMediaRequest(@RequestBody RequestDetails requestDetails ,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("****************** createMediaRequest Method of the controller gets invoked 123 *****************");
        if(requestDetails!=null){
            System.out.println("******************* Requestdetails Is Been Object is been received ***************" + requestDetails.getRequestId());
        }

        //Sending the HttpPostRequest
        StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(); 
        String serverUrl = "http://localhost:8080/raws/createMediaRequest.raws"; //get it from app_properpties table
        url.append(serverUrl);

        System.out.println("************** Started creating the Httpost request ********************");
        final HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 10000);

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
        HttpPost httppostRequest = new HttpPost(serverUrl);
        httppostRequest.setEntity(new SerializableEntity(requestDetails,false));

        System.out.println("************** Finished creating the Http Post request ********************");

        System.out.println("*********** Before sending the Httppost Request ******************");

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httppostRequest);

        System.out.println("*********** After sending teh Httppost Request ******************");
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
```

On the receiver application's controller I am trying to deserialize the domain object received in the POST request. Both of the Application A and B have the RequestDetails class available in the workspace but in both of the case the package hierachy for the domain object is different.Say for example in Application A RequestDetails object is available in com.test and in application B it is available in the com.test123. Below is the code on the receiver application's controller.

```
RequestMapping(value = "/createMediaRequest.raws", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Object createMediaRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    System.out.println("***************** MediaWorkflowController Received Media Request *******************");

    try{
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(request.getInputStream());
        RequestDetails requestDetails=(RequestDetails)in.readObject();
        if(requestDetails!=null){
            System.out.println("requestdetails object is not null *******************" + requestDetails.getRequestId());
        }
    }   
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Below is the code for the RequestDetails.java on Application A

```
package com.test;
public class RequestDetails implements java.io.Serializable{

    String requestId;        

    public String getRequestId() {
        return requestId;
    }
    public void setRequestId(String requestId) {
        this.requestId = requestId;
    }
}
```

Below is the code for the RequestDetails.java on Application B

```
package com.test123;
public class RequestDetails implements java.io.Serializable{

    String requestId;        

    public String getRequestId() {
        return requestId;
    }
    public void setRequestId(String requestId) {
        this.requestId = requestId;
    }
}
```

I am getting the below exception when the code for the receiver application's controller get executed.

```
****************** createMediaRequest Method of the controller gets invoked 123 *****************
******************* Requestdetails Is Been Object is been received ***************12345
************** Started creating the Httpost request ********************
************** Finished creating the Http Post request ********************
*********** Before sending the Httppost Request ******************
***************** MediaWorkflowController Received Media Request *******************
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.RequestDetails
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1612)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at com.cira.raws.mediawf.api.services.controller.MediaWFController.createMediaRequest(MediaWFController.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
*********** After sending teh Httppost Request ******************
```

As per my understanding the issue has occured while deserializing the object. If I am keeping the same package hierachy on both of the sides for the RequestDetails class the code is working fine.Is it compulsory to have the same package hierarchy for the RequestDetails domain object? If no  how to resolve the issue I am facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deserialise the object you need to have the same class in both instances. This includes the package name of the class.

As you have said the packages are different then the failure you are seeing is easy to understand.

Comment: But isn't there a workaround of the problem by not sending the package information while serializing the java object?

Comment: No. The package name is VERY important. A class with the same name can exist in several package. To figure out which class you want you need to specify the package also; i.e. the fully qualified class name.

Comment: I have checked many posts saying that binary serialization is to be used only when absolutly required.One of them is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794868/how-to-send-serialized-object-to-a-servlet-using-apache-httpclient. Can you please tell me what are the possible issues or drawbacks of the binary serialization?

Comment: One of the drawback of binary serialisation is what you have encountered. Also it is slower than the other methods mentioned because it uses the Java Reflection API under the hood. JSON is also faster (less verbose) than XML.